# Find zeros in a Factorial Number Explanation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I didn't understand this question :

**Determine whether 30! ends in exactly seven zeros, justify your answer.**

so I need Explanation for this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here for hints : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64080/zeros-of-the-decimal-representation-of-k?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 30! ends in exactly 7 zeros. When an integer ends with a zero, it means that it has a factor of 10 or of 5 and 2. For each extra zero it ends with, it has extra factors of 10/5 and 2. For example if it ends with 10 zeros, it has 10 factors of 10 or 10 factors of 5 and 10 factors of 2. It is, for this reason, we can figure out how many zeros 30! has. Any number x factorial such that x is a natural number means that itself and every natural number below it is a factor. We just need to determine which of those factors have factors of 5 or 2 and how many. In 30! the factors that have factors of 5 are 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, and 30. Each of these numbers has 1 factor of five except 25 which has 2. So in total there are 7 factors of five. Now since every even number has a factor of 2, there are at least 15 factors of 2 which is more than enough for each to multiply with a 5 to make a factor of 10. So in total, there are 7 zeros at the end because there are 7 factors of 10.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @JimHenry Yeah, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Number of zeroes is equal to exponent of 10, that is equal to exponent of 5 as well in 30 factorial.
30/5 + 30/25 convert to greatest integer function, 
Ans is 6+1= 7